# request mapping with different parameters list in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, overloading

Method1 : It accepts entity and image as request parameters

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method={RequestMethod.POST}, params={"entity", "image"})
public String add( @RequestParam("entity") CustomEntity entity,
                @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {
LOGGER.trace("Information with Image");
return "success";
}
```

Method2 : It accepts only entity and image s request parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method={RequestMethod.POST}, params={"entity")
public String add( @RequestParam("entity") CustomEntity entity) {
LOGGER.trace("Information without Image");
return "success";
}
```

When iam testing using Spring Rest API it raises 400 bad request

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
map.add("entity", new CustomEntity());
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI+"/add", map, String.class);
```

what i need to change?
[Link] ([In a Spring controller, can I have a method called based on the number of request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749023/in-a-spring-controller-can-i-have-a-method-called-based-on-the-number-of-reques))

Comment: Maybe the problem is you are sending empty value while spring is expecting one at a parameter.

Comment: @DarshanLila [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749023/in-a-spring-controller-can-i-have-a-method-called-based-on-the-number-of-reques)

Comment: What do you use to convert String <-> CustomEntity, and did you control (though debugger or better wireshark) the actual content of your request ?